# What PCI-E graphics card suitable for motherboard: Biostar TPower I45?

Tags: graphics-card

Fried my Asus PCI-E graphics card (white smoke).

Motherboard: Biostar TPower I45.
What graphics card can I replace it with,
that meets these criteria:

- I can just slot it in, attach the PCI-E cable, and boot
- low cost

Comment: PSU: Antec 650 Watt output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PCI Express cards and motherboards are fully compatible with any version.  Either the board or the card will scale back to meet the other component's capabilities.  The primary limiting factor is power, so you will need to research the other aspects of a new video card around your power supply.